# Display auto-increment values of a counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter

I wish to animate a counter from 0 to a given value.

I've tried with a `for()` loop, but it freezes and then only displays the end value.

// HTML

```
<input type="hidden" value="100000" id="amount"/>
<input type="text" value="0" id="count"/>
<input type="button" value="run" id="runner"/>​
```

// JS

```
$('#runner').click(function(){
   var amount=parseInt($('#amount').val());
   for(i=0;i<=amount;i++)
   {
      $('#count').val(i);
       setTimeout(1);
   }
});
```

​You can see it here : http://jsfiddle.net/P4Xy6/1/

Any idea on how I could display the values between 0 and the given value ? Or any better way to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice is to avoid setTimeout/Interval when using jQuery, because this library already provides means for asynchronous function calls, for example:

```
$('#runner').click(function() {
   var amount = parseInt($('#amount').val());

   $({c: 0}).animate({c: amount}, {
        step: function(now) {
            $("#count").val(Math.round(now))
        },
        duration: 3000,
        easing: "linear"
    });
})
```

This animates the counter from `0` to `amount` in 3 seconds.

http://jsfiddle.net/zQWRM/2/

Comment: Perfect answer ! This is exactly what I need (without explained it clearly...) Amounts are millions, so this "duration" parameter is the better way to do it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

This should do it ..

```
$('#runner').click(function(){
   var amount=parseInt($('#amount').val());
   var counter = 0;
   var interval = setInterval(function(){
      $('#count').val(counter++);
      if (counter > amount){
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
   },100); // the value 100 is the time delay between increments to the counter
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/rbZq3/

And a more optimized one (*by caching the reference to the `#count` element*) at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/rbZq3/2/

Comment: +1 for you both ! @Gaby aka G. Petrioli It works fine, but the duration is too long (even at 1ms), because my amounts are in millions. How to do it faster ? $('#count').val(counter+1000); ?

Comment: @Valky, yes.. if setting it at 1ms is not fast enough, then you will need to increase the increment value .. change `counter++` to `counter+=10`

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  animateCount : function (from, to, time) {
    var steps = 1,
        self = this,
        counter;

    if (from - to > 0) {
      steps = -1;
    };

    from -= steps;

    function step() {
      self.val(from += steps);

      if ((steps < 0 && to >= from) || (steps > 0 && from >= to)) {
        clearInterval(counter);
      };
    };

    counter = setInterval(step, time || 100);
  }
});
```

Then in your click function call it :

```
$('#runner').click(function() {
    $('#count').animateCount(1,100);
})​
```

first param is start number, second is final number, third param is (optional) interval timer

Working example here : http://jsfiddle.net/P4Xy6/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
var amount=parseInt($('#amount').val());
var i = parseInt($('#count').val());
var tim;

function run(){
    clearInterval(tim);
    tim = setInterval(function(){
        $('#count').val(++i);
    },100);        
}

$('#runner').click(function(){
    run();
});
```

<kbd>[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LNE48/9/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" value="100000" id="amount"/>
<input type="text" value="0" id="count"/>
<input type="button" value="run" id="runner"/>​
```

JavaScript:

```
var maxAmount = 5;

$('#runner').click(function(){
   setInterval(
       function() {
           var amount = $('#amount').val();
           if(amount < maxAmount)
           {
               amount++;
               $('#amount').attr('value', amount);
               $('#count').attr('value', amount);        
           }
           else
           {
               clearInterval();
           }
       },
       500   
   );
});
```

Here is the solution on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P4Xy6/10/